# SQL Rating Score System

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called tbl_Banners.  This table stores banners to display on my website.  Attached to this table is a field for zip code (ba_zip_code).  The zip code is used to display banners closest to the users viewing the site.  I also have a relational table called tbl_Banners_links that stores categories for different types of vehicles.  This table contains the following fields:

```
bal_id (unique ID), ba_id (banner ID), and vc_id (vehicle category ID)
```

Each banner can have multiple vehicle category links (such as Car, Truck, SUV, etc.)

I want to provide a rating score for certain criteria, including miles from users location, vehicle category, and banner priority (ba_priority).

Here is the result set for my data and scores that have been applied for each banner, based upon the SQL statement BELOW this table:

[image]

```
SELECT ba.ba_id, ba.ba_url, ba.ba_filename, bal.vc_id,
(CASE WHEN ba.ba_priority = 1 THEN 40 ELSE 0 END) As ba_priority, 
(CASE WHEN bal.vc_id = 1 THEN 50 ELSE 0 END) As vc_id_score, 
(CASE 
WHEN dbo.CalcDistancebetweenGeoLocations(45.751671, -87.08951, [ba_latitude], [ba_longitude], 0) <= 30 THEN 40 
WHEN dbo.CalcDistancebetweenGeoLocations(45.751671, -87.08951, [ba_latitude], [ba_longitude], 0) > 30 AND dbo.CalcDistancebetweenGeoLocations(45.751671, -87.08951, [ba_latitude], [ba_longitude], 0) <= 60 THEN 30 
WHEN dbo.CalcDistancebetweenGeoLocations(45.751671, -87.08951, [ba_latitude], [ba_longitude], 0) > 60 AND dbo.CalcDistancebetweenGeoLocations(45.751671, -87.08951, [ba_latitude], [ba_longitude], 0) <= 100 THEN 20 
WHEN dbo.CalcDistancebetweenGeoLocations(45.751671, -87.08951, [ba_latitude], [ba_longitude], 0) > 100 THEN 0 ELSE 0 END) As ba_distance 
INTO #MyTempBannerTable 
FROM tbl_Banners ba 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Banners_links bal ON bal.ba_id = ba.ba_id 
WHERE ba.ba_active = 1 AND ba.ba_c_id = 1;
```

The rating score works like such (or I want it to):

```
ba_priority = 1 = 40 points
mileage 0-29 = 40 points
mileage 30-59 = 30 points
mileage 60-99 = 20 points
mileage 100+ = 0 points
vc_id = selected vc_id = 50 points
```

I need the code to add up all of these and total for each banner based upon the criteria.  As you can see from the result set below, if a banner has multiple vc_id listed, it TOTALS all of the scores for each vc_id for that particular banner.  It should only grab the unique banner score.  So a banner that has the following:

```
mileage 0-29 = 40
ba_priority = 40
vc_id = 50
Total = 130 points
```

Instead, it is totaling up to 890 points.

I need to order by TOTAL SCORE and grab just the top 5 banners, using this code:

```
SELECT TOP 5 ba_id, ba_url, ba_filename, SUM(vc_id_score + ba_distance + ba_priority) As RatingScore 
FROM #MyTempBannerTable 
GROUP BY ba_id, ba_url, ba_filename 
ORDER BY RatingScore DESC, NEWID()
```

Here is the result set:

[image]

I hope I made sense and didn't confuse you and myself with this issue.

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with the current query you have?

Comment: For instance, ba_id 105 has multiple records in the bal_id link table. It is adding up all rows, so rather than giving that one banner a score of 40 for distance, it's adding up 20+ rows for a score of 800+. That one banner should only get a score 1x for each score rating (distance, priority, vehicle category). In theory, if a banner met all criteria, it's max score should only be 130 (40 distance, 40 priority, and 50 vehicle category). As you can see, ba_id has a score of 890.